# Converting Json to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am having some trouble converting a nested Json file into a data frame.

```
{'response': {'status': 'ok',
  'userTier': 'developer',
  'total': 742,
  'startIndex': 1,
  'pageSize': 10,
  'currentPage': 1,
  'pages': 75,
  'orderBy': 'relevance',
  'results':              [{'id': 'world/live/2022/jun/01/russia-ukraine-war-biden-approves- 
                          medium-range-rocket-systems-to-bolster-ukraine-defences-live',
                          'type': 'liveblog',
                          'sectionId': 'world',
                          'sectionName': 'World news',
                          'webPublicationDate': '2022-06-01T05:19:54Z',
                          'webTitle': 'Russia-Ukraine war: Biden approves medium-range rocket 
                           systems to bolster Ukraine defences –\xa0live ',
                          'webUrl': 'https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2022/jun/01/russia- 
                           ukraine-war-biden-approves-medium-range-rocket-systems-to-bolster- 
                           ukraine-defences-live',
                           'apiUrl': 
                           'https://content.guardianapis.com/world/live/2022/jun/01/russia- 
                            ukraine-war-biden-approves-medium-range-rocket-systems-to-bolster- 
                            ukraine-defences-live',
                           'isHosted': False,
                           'pillarId': 'pillar/news',
                           'pillarName': 'News'},
```

This is an excerpt.

I have written this code to turn the dictionary into a dataframe:

```
df_aus = pd.json_normalize(dictionary_aus, record_path=['response','results'])
df_aus
```

But the dataframe is being made with only 10 rows when there should be over 700.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.DataFrame(dictionary_aus['response']['results'])`?

Comment: I just tried that then, It's doing the same thing(only making a dataframe with 10 rows). I must be missing something.

Comment: What's the output of `len(dictionary_aus['response']['results'])`

Comment: only 10, I'm not sure what I have done wrong. Because it should be 742

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong I made a mistake when I was using API. Thank you for your help Adid